# Power BI sorting irrespective of number

Tags: powerbi, data-visualization, visualization

I have one Power BI report that has bar graph in it. I need sorting to work out irrespective of the value that it is bringing in.

For example, see the sample dashboard:

[image]

The dashboard shows immigration population of certain countries from 1920-2010. There are few countries displaying negative values. Those countries are shown in Bottom 5 in the chart. The chart is sorted by descending order by Population of Immigration (as clearly seen)

What  I want to sort the chart based on the bar size instead of population.

Hence, the countries that would show up in bar graph should be in below order:

Syria 
 China 
 Libya 
 ... 
 Australia (50) 
 **USA** (having value as -42)
  UK (41) 
 **Sweden** (having value as -35)

 Srilanka (31) 
 ... (so forth)

How do I make that happen? If I take population as a parameter, I am not getting "negative countries" near the "positive" ones.

Hope I am clear with the example

Regards

**EDIT**: After adding Absolute value

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an "Absolute Migration" measure - something like:

```
Abs Migration = ABS ( [Net Migration] )
```

Add this measure to the Tooltip section of your bar chart visualisation. You can still choose not to display tooltips.

Now click `...` on your bar chart and choose `Sort By > Abs Migration`

[image]

Example PBIX file: https://pwrbi.com/so_55806187/

### EDIT

Based on updated requirements in your comments below, you need to create two MEASURES:

Measure **Average Value**:

```
Average Value = AVERAGE ( MyData[Value] )
```

Measure **ABS Average Value**:

```
ABS Average Value = ABS ( [Average Value] )
```

In your bar chart, put `Attribute` in the Axis, `Average Value` in Value, and `ABS Average Value` in Tooltips. Click `...` and `Sort By > ABS Average Value`. Format to suit:

[image]

Comment: I tried ABS function, but then I'm not getting what I was expecting! (see edited question!)

Comment: Read my answer carefully - add the `Abs Migration` measure to the TOOLTIP. See the example PBIX in my answer.

Comment: Yes I did that and in-fact I am able to regenerate the result at my end. Wanted to know if the same will work for Average Aggregation instead of sum!?

Comment: Yes I am trying in my real project and using average aggregation I am not seeing the sorting working

Comment: Impossible to answer, without seeing your data and code.

Comment: In our example I just added one more rows for same country e.g. India with value as "12" so that it will take average of the values (90+12=102/2 = 51) and then taking the average of Net values and Avg of absolute values, I see the chart getting screwed!

Comment: What are your measures? To get a meaningful answer, your question should contain enough realistic data, and your actual code, to replicate your problem...

Comment: I can't share you the PBI file as the datasource is the JSON file but I have exported the table (from JSON) into excel and uploaded at my google drive. Available for download at https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JwBRVH9Ha3CZusuGIMMoDRvFJKXUnNql/view?usp=sharing

Comment: From the excel sheet please ignore the Customer Column. I am trying to build chart with "Attributes" on Y-Axis and "Value" on X-axis in such a way that the average value of "Value" column is sorted based on Absolute value of "Value" column

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192266/discussion-between-olly-and-romil-n).